# If we know a sha256 hashed value and its message length can we find the message?

Tags: sha-256, preimage-resistance

Is it possible to find the original message if we know a sha256 hashed value and its message length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the message length. If the length is 1 byte (2 bytes, 3 bytes, ...) - it is trivial to do an exhaustive search to find the message that maps into the known hash. The longer the message - the harder it gets.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is still non-trivial to reverse the hash. However, knowing the message length and allowed characters places an upper bound on the number of possible messages.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's (quite) trivial for 1,2,3 bytes. Not doing the reverse of a hash, but simply having the possibility to calculate 256/65536/16777216 hashes and compare for a match. The good old and simple brute force attack.